# Programmatically "stop" Sagemaker instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, shutdown

I can automatically shutdown a sagemaker instance as indicated here, by using lifecycle configuration

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609409/automatically-stop-sagemaker-notebook-instance-after-inactivity
```

Is there a way to achieve this programmatically, by means of any ''image terminal'' command?
By image terminal, it is meant the Linux shell that can be opened via ''Launcher'' in ''Sagemaker Studio''

My use case is large computational jobs, where the idle inactive time in the automatic solution would be quite expensive.
It would be useful to have a `shutdown_instance()`, to be added as last command in lengthy shell scripts

Comment: "image terminal command" ? What is "image" terminal. Sadly your question is unclear and lacks details.

Comment: Details have been added

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar with Sagemaker JupyterLab notebooks. (We have some long-running analytics which will *eventually* move to lambdas or similar, but for now are [Notebook Scheduled Jobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/create-notebook-auto-run.html)). As the instances are bundled up in Apps (you'll note that commands like List_Instances() don't show these up!), we needed to:

1. Identify what app is driving the notebook.
2. Delete that app.

We run this as the last cell of the notebook. This is in Python, but you can just use the equivalent commands in the AWS CLI for the same effect in any bash script.

```py
def Cleanup_Notebook_Resouces():
    log_path = '/opt/ml/metadata/resource-metadata.json'
    with open(log_path, 'r') as logs:
        AppDetails = json.load(logs)
    AppDetails

    AppDetails["AppName"] = AppDetails.pop("ResourceName")
    AppDetails.pop("ResourceArn")
    AppDetails.pop("AppImageVersion")

    sage = boto3.client("sagemaker")

    try:
        sage.delete_app(**AppDetails)

    except sage.exceptions.ClientError:
        print("***" + AppDetails["AppName"] + " App Likely already deleted ***")
        print("Current apps:")
        print()
        [print(a, "\n") for a in sage.list_apps()["Apps"]]
```

The same *should* be possible for true notebook instances... You can use `boto3.client("sagemaker").List_Notebook_Instances()` - the metadata logs may include a helpful resource name you can use as per the below, but I've not verified that.